# Extracting selected columns to new DataFrame as a copy in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I have the following intent classification data (4 columns, 65 rows):**

Columns:     **intent-A**       **intent-B**       **intent-C**       **intent-D**

records:             d1a                   d1b                   d1c                    d1d
                             d2a                     d2b                   d2c                    d2d

**I am attempting to combine the columns into two columns to look like this (2 columns, 260 rows):**

**data**     **intent**

d1a    intent-A
d1b      intent-B
d1c      intent-C
d1d      intent-D

d2a      intent-A

d2b        intent-B

d2c        intent-C

d2d        intent-D

**I am using pandas DataFrame and have tried using different functions with no success (append, concat, etc.). Any help would be most appreciated!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
df.melt(value_vars=df.columns, var_name='intent', value_name='data')

     intent data
0  intent-A  d1a
1  intent-A  d2a
2  intent-B  d1b
3  intent-B  d2b
4  intent-C  d1c
5  intent-C  d2c
6  intent-D  d1d
7  intent-D  d2d
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code, (here df is your data frame)-

`pd.DataFrame({"Date":df.values.flatten(), "intent":df.columns.tolist()*65})`